# Execution Stuck in C Program

Tags: c, function, precision

I am working through a simple problem set in C to design a quadratic equation solving program, but for some reason I can't get it working. I've tried working through each piece and pulling them into their own programs to test their execution, and individually they seem to work, but when I execute the program, it gets stuck. Any help is appreciated!

```
//A program to solve a quadratic equation
#include <stdio.h>

float absoluteValue (float x)
{
        if (x < 0)
        x = -x;
        return (x);
}

float squareRoot (float x)
{
        const float epsilon = .00001;
        float guess = 1.0;

        while (absoluteValue (guess * guess - x) >= epsilon )
                guess = (x / guess + guess) / 2.0;
                return guess;
}

float quadraticEquation (float a, float b, float c)
{
         float rootOne, rootTwo;

        if ((b * b - 4 * a * c) <= 0) {
                printf ("The roots are imaginary.");
        }
        else {
                rootOne = (-b + squareRoot(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
                rootTwo = (-b - squareRoot(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
        }

        return 0;

}

int main (void)
{
        float a, b, c;
        a = 10;
        b = 30;
        c = 5;

//      printf ("Please enter a value fo A, B, and C: \n");
//      scanf ("%f%f%f", &a, &b, &c);
        quadraticEquation(a, b, c);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more as to what "gets stuck" means?

Comment: First split up your expressions into smaller parts, so each part is evaluated separately. Store in temporary variables that you then put together for the more complex expressions. Then use a debugger to step through the code, line by line, while monitoring the variables and their values (here's why the first step is crucial). That way you should easily understand when, where and why you have such a problem.

Comment: Sorry, when I say "Get stuck" I mean if I execute it in my terminal nothing happens... it just sits without printing anything. So I am sure it is stuck in a loop, I just haven't been able to figure out where/how

Comment: As an example of breaking up expressions, take `absoluteValue (guess * guess - x)`. It can be broken up into `float tmp1 = guess * guess; float tmp2 = tmp1 - x; float tmp3 = absoluteValue(tmp2);` Then use `tmp3` (or whatever you name them) in the condition as `tmp3 >= epsilon`.

Comment: Use `double` instead of `float`. `float` is less accurate.

Comment: The only place where it can stuck is the while loop in function SquareRoot() so focus on that. BLUEPIXY has a good advise. Try to understand why the result fails to converge.

Comment: This would be a great opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Note that the quadratic function has no way to report the real roots. It sets two local variables but neither prints nor returns them.  However, this does not cause the code to hang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a program that's getting stuck in a loop, the best way to find out where it's happening is to run your program in a debugger, let it get stuck, and then pause the debugger. In GDB or LLDB this can be done by typing Control-C, but in other debuggers the UI may be different (in GUI-based IDEs, there will probably be a button you can click on); however, every debugger should have a pause feature. This will cause the debugger to show you exactly where execution is at the point it's stuck, allowing you to quickly ascertain where the problem is.

Anyway, in this case, the lines that are causing the infinite loop are:

```
while (absoluteValue (guess * guess - x) >= epsilon )
    guess = (x / guess + guess) / 2.0;
```

By stepping through and using the debugger to analyze the contents of the variables, the execution at the point at which it gets stuck is:

`x` is 700.

`guess` is 26.4575119, which isn't far off from the square root of 700.

`guess * guess - x` is -0.0000610351563, whose absolute value is greater than `epsilon`, which is 0.00001.

`guess` is then set to the value of `(x / guess + guess) / 2.0`, which comes out to 26.4575119. Unfortunately, this is the same value `guess` already had, so the loop continues forever.

Basically, floating-point imprecision is causing your result never to get within `epsilon` of the correct answer. You could adjust your algorithm to fix this, but unless this is for some assignment that requires you not to use anything other than stdio or something, I recommend instead having a look at `math.h`, which contains a `sqrt` function that will calculate the square root for you, rather than reinventing the wheel yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Unfortunately I cannot use other libraries so I had to fix this. I checked it with GDB as you suggested so I could follow your logic. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, `math.h` is part of the C standard library, which you're already using `printf` from, so...

Comment: One way to handle the problem is to use a relative difference, such as: `static inline double reldiff(double x, double y)
{
    double divisor = fmax(fabs(x), fabs(y));
    /* If divisor is zero, both x and y are zero, so the difference */
    /* between them is zero */
    if (divisor == 0.0)
        return 0.0;
    return fabs(x - y) / divisor;
}` — where `fmax()` and `fabs()` are declared in `<math.h>` but can be provided easily enough if you're not allowed to use the standard versions.  You compare this result against an appropriate limit, such as `1.0E-6` (one part in a million).

Comment: Note, too, that the problem with the fixed epsilon was bad because the value of `x` was 700; however, you have the converse problem if the value of `x` is tiny — say `1E-14`.  The loop can finish long before you've got a good approximation to the square root.

Comment: I just want to clear something up because there have been a lot of great suggestions. 

1) The problem I was working on specifically required me to use the squareroot function listed in the problem which is why I didn't use sqrt as was recommended by some.

Comment: 2) Good call with the debugger.

3) To someone well versed in programming a floating point imprecision issue may be apparent, but to someone new to coding like myself, this is a totally new issue I haven't run into. Additionally, if I had of tested lower values in A, B, and C the program would have seemed to have worked (I tested it to work with a = 5, b = 30 and c = 3). Therefore when reading through my code looking for obvious answers (as someone new would do) this floating point imprecision was not something that would have crossed my mind at all. In the future it will. Also, thanks GDB